# How to create a widget automatically multiple times with different data being passes from an array?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example,

Let there be a Widget called TestButton :

```
class TestButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function x;
  final String text;
  TestButton(this.x,this.text);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: x,
      child: Text(
       text,
       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
      ),
   );
 }
}
```

Instead of writing:

```
TestButton(increaseCounter,'text1');
TestButton(increaseCounter,'text2');
TestButton(increaseCounter,'text3');
```

To create 3 buttons with text : text1 , text2 ,text3

How do I make flutter read data from an array, to create as many buttons as there are elements in the array and the data of each element to be passed as the second positional argument.

```
var a=['test1','test2','test3'];//array example
```

Comment: a sample code snippet for the above program would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ListView.builder`. something like this :

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: a.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return TestButton(increaseCounter,a[index]);
        },

      )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Column(
children:[
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
     TestButton(increaseCounter,a[i])
    ],
 )
```

Or

```
Column (
children: a.map((txt)=>TestButton(increaseCounter,txt)).toList()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a widget multiple times using List.generate, then add that List as childen to Column, Stack etc.

Example:

```
Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: List.generate(3, (index) => InkWell(
                onTap: () => changeState(index2),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    child: Center(child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text("Cell",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),),
                        Text("${index+1}",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              )
      ),
```

Note: Make sure you don't add List as "childen: [ List.generate...]"  This can give error.

Instead use "childen: List.generate..."